# (Xna) My players position won't update, I need it for my enemy to follow

Tags: c#, xna

`enter code here`When im drawing it to a string it just stays at 300,300 . My mouse always updates its Vector2 position.X, position.Y. I need to be able to update my players position or my enemy wont follow my player. It just goes to that certain player position i set for it. PLEASE HELP AND THANK YOU!

```
class Enemy
    {
        Player p = new Player();

        public Vector2 direction, velocity,position;
        public float speed;
        public Texture2D texture;

        public Enemy()
        {
            speed = 1;
            texture = null;
            position = new Vector2(600, 500);

        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("circle");
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

            direction = p.position - position;
            direction.Normalize();
            velocity = direction * speed;
            position += velocity;   
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.Red);

        }


        /*
        direction = p.position - position;
        direction.Normalize();
        velocity = direction * speed;
        position += velocity; 
         */
    }

class Player
    {
        public float rotation, bulletDelay;
        public Vector2 position,velocity,origin;
        public string spriteName;
        public Texture2D texture,bulletTexture;
        List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
        public float speed = 10;
        public float health = 100;

        public Player()
        {
            texture = null;
            spriteName = "playerover";
            position = new Vector2(300, 300);
            bulletDelay = 20;

        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(spriteName);
            bulletTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("playerbullet");
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            origin = new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2);

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, texture.Width, texture.Height), null, Color.White, rotation,new Vector2(texture.Width / 2, texture.Height / 2), SpriteEffects.None, 0);

            foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
            {
                bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);
            }
        }

        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            MouseState curMouse = Mouse.GetState();

            KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

            Vector2 mouseLoc = new Vector2(curMouse.X, curMouse.Y);

            Vector2 direction = mouseLoc - position;

            rotation = (float)(Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X));

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                position.Y -= speed;

            }

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            {
                position.Y += speed;

            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            {
                position.X -= speed;

            }
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {
                position.X += speed;

            }

            if (curMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                Shoot();
            }
            UpdateBullets();
        }

        public void UpdateBullets()
        {
            foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
            {
                bullet.position += bullet.velocity;
                if (bullet.position.Y <= 5)
                {
                    bullet.isVisible = false;
                }

                if (bullet.position.X <= 5)
                {
                    bullet.isVisible = false;
                }

                if (bullet.position.X >= 785)
                {
                    bullet.isVisible = false;
                }

                if (bullet.position.Y >= 575)
                {
                    bullet.isVisible = false;
                }

            }



                for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!bullets[i].isVisible)
                    {
                        bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                        i--;
                    }

                }


        }

        public void Shoot()
        {


            if (bulletDelay >= 0)
                bulletDelay--;


            if (bulletDelay <= 0)
            {

                Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(bulletTexture);
                newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 5f + velocity;
                newBullet.position = position + newBullet.velocity * 5;
                newBullet.isVisible = true;

                if (bullets.Count < 20)
                {
                    bullets.Add(newBullet);
                }
            }

            if (bulletDelay == 0)
            {
                bulletDelay = 20;
            }
        }
    }


class Hud
    {
        public SpriteFont font;
        public bool showHud;
        Player p = new Player();
        Enemy e = new Enemy();


        public Hud()
        {
            showHud = true;  
        }

        public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
        {
            font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
                if (showHud)
                 {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Mouse.X = " + mouse.X, new Vector2(10, 0), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Mouse.Y = " + mouse.Y, new Vector2(10, 20), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Health = " + p.health, new Vector2(10, 40), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Pos.Y = " + p.position.Y, new Vector2(10, 60), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Pos.X = " + p.position.X, new Vector2(10, 80), Color.White);
                 }       
            }


    }
```

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to help you. I take that back. There is *no* information in this question to help you. You need to post your code, other than that, *you got a bug* is the best anyone can do.

Comment: If this is not enough information i will make a video on the problem.

Comment: Sorry im new to this.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read all the code you posted, but it seems that you created a new separate instance for the player in the Enemy class which is never updated.

```
class Enemy 
{ 
    Player p = new Player();
    //...
}
```

You should either take a `Vector2` for the players position into your enemies `Update` method or handle the enemy movement somewhere else. Perhaps you could have a method in your Enemy class named `Follow` taking a Player object as a parameter, then you could do something like the following in the place where you handle all entity movement. It would look roughly like this:

```
public void UpdateEntities(GameTime gameTime)
{
    player.Update(gameTime);
    enemy.Update(gameTime);

    if(PlayerDistanceFromEnemy() < 50)
        enemy.Follow(player);
}
```

That is a very rough guideline and probably something you'd want to rewrite later on, but it will work.

as for the `Follow` method in your enemy class:

```
public void Follow(Player player)
{
    this.p = player;
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if(p != null)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This will work, but you have to work on the structure of your code if you want to expand. I might update this answer later with a better solution if someone doesn't do it before me.

Comment: No problem, you should also consider making a base class named `Mob` from which you derive your player and enemy classes. Should make things much easier in the long run.

Comment: Ok, I will buid a Obj Class.